# how would i send a picture as part of an email progmaticly

Tags: java, android, email

hi guys making a simple email app for a friend.. it will send him info for part of his business. but it also sometimes needs a photo attaching. ive solved the opening of the camera and taking and saving the picture to the devices memory using this piece of code

```
 public class CameraDemoActivity extends Activity {
int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
public static int count = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store
    // pics taken by the camera using this application.
    final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
    File newdir = new File(dir);
    newdir.mkdirs();

    Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
            // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
            // and likewise.
            count++;
            String file = dir+count+".jpg";
            File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
    }
}
```

}

how would i now attach this to an email with in the app? any help always appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i guess you are going to use intent to send the mail, just add this while building your intent :

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
```